# how to enter a base value and an override value on excel

Tags: excel, vba

Let me explain it with an example.

I'm pulling Sales data from a website and doing calculations on it, so that for instance I would have two columns:

```
Sales Company A | 15000 (from the website)
Sales Company B | 24000 (from the website)
-----------------------
Total           | sum()
```

I want to be able to override the sales so that it impacts the total, but not to lose the original value. So for instance I could change the company A sales manually on my cell, hit enter and get a new total. And if i made a mistake, i can just delete the company A sales and it will go back to the original 15000 (without the need to retrieve the data again i would hope).

Is this possible on excel? Or an addin or something that allows it?

Comment: *'Let me explain it with an example.'* translation: I'm going to provide a description and I want someone to do all the work for me.

Comment: not really, i can write a program myself but i'm sure this has been done before and probably it's even an included Excel feature that so far I haven't been able to find. Don't be so judgmental, it's one of my few questions on stackoverflow after years of only using it for my searches.

Comment: How about just starting another column with the manually entered data?

Comment: Maybe you should work with two sheets. One contains original values, the other(s) for outside values.

Comment: Yeah I can think of several workarounds. Like you said, for instance create 2 sheets, one with the original and one with the override that would pull the data from the original if the cell is empty. But that requires for me to duplicate the sheet and add code to every cell (probably i can do that on vb somehow). So there is no easy way to achieve this on excel?

Comment: What's wrong with Undo?

Comment: lol, the idea is to make this with several hundredth cells that you can modify freely, save, load it up again a week later and keep making changes. If you suddenly realized after weeks that the original value is better than the one you are using, you can just delete that cell and use the original value. So yeah, you can't use undo.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems there is no easy way but to code it. So here it's my code on vba, the way it works:
1) Create a sheet called Original, which will contain the original data.
2) Copy/duplicate the sheet and call it Editable which will contain the editable data that you want to override or not.

The following code works that if you modify the cell at C1 it will copy two full ranges of styles and formulas from Original to Editable. Then if you modify any other cell, it will turn that cell blue because you modified it. If you delete a cell, it will recover the value from Original formula cell.

I hope this helps someone else, the code is pretty simple and easy to modify. I just wish there was some other better way without requiring to duplicate sheets which in my case are pretty large.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' if C1 is modified, copy most of the data from Original to Editable
    If target.Column = 3 And target.Row = 1 Then
        sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet
    Else
        If IsEmpty(target.Value) Then ' if we delete this cell, copy it from Original to Editable
            Sheets("Original").Cells(target.Column, target.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Editable").Cells(target.Column, target.Row)
         Else
            If Not target.Cells.HasFormula Then ' if the copied cell is not formula, it means it's modified value so change its color
                target.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 42 ' change cell color since you have edited manually this cell
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub

    'In this example I am Copying the Data from Original to Editable sheets
    Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' copy the required data
    Sheets("Original").Range("L3:V13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Editable").Range("L3")
    Sheets("Original").Range("A50:AM172").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Editable").Range("A50")
    'CopyCharts "Editable"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```